# F# list pattern matching limitations or just bad writing?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Given some `CreditScoreInput`:

```ml
type CreditScoreInput = { id: string; score: string; years: int }

let input = [
    { id = "CUSTOMER001"; score = "Medium"; years = 1 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER001"; score = "Medium"; years = 1 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER002"; score = "Medium"; years = 10 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER003"; score = "Bad"; years = 0 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER003"; score = "Bad"; years = 0 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER003"; score = "Bad"; years = 0 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER004"; score = "Good"; years = 0 }
    { id = "CUSTOMER005"; score = "Good"; years = 10 }
]
```

My function `validateDuplicates` is out looking for duplicates:

```ml
let validate list =
    match list with
    | [] -> failwith "No customers supplied!"
    | _ -> list

let validateDuplicates (group:string * list<CreditScoreInput>) =
    match group with
    | (id, g) when g.Length = 1 -> printf $"No duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, [input1; input2]) -> printf $"Two duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, g) when g.Length > 2 -> printf $"More than two duplicates for {id} is NOT OK.\n"

    true

input
|> validate
|> List.groupBy (fun i -> i.id)
|> List.forall (fun i -> i |> validateDuplicates)
|> ignore
```

Inside of `validateDuplicates` I notice a little squiggly under `group`, leading to the warning:

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value `(_,[_;_;_])` may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s). However, a pattern rule with a `when` clause might successfully match this value.

Is there a way I can play nice with the compiler to avoid this warning?

#### Update

I am not sure whether I should do this here but here are my changes based on the excellent guidance:

```ml
let validateDuplicates (group:string * list<CreditScoreInput>) =
    match group with
    | (id, [_]) -> printf $"No duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, [_; _]) -> printf $"Two duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, g) -> printf $"More than two duplicates for {id} is NOT OK.\n"

input
|> validate
|> List.groupBy (fun i -> i.id)
|> List.iter (fun i -> i |> validateDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of the last `when` clause, because you know it will always be true:

```ml
    match group with
    | (id, g) when g.Length = 1 -> printf $"No duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, [input1; input2]) -> printf $"Two duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | (id, g) -> printf $"More than two duplicates for {id} is NOT OK.\n"
```

Proof:

- `g.Length` can never be negative or 0
- If `g.Length` is 1 then it will match the first case
- If `g.Length` is 2 then it will match the second case
- Therefore, `g.Length` will always be > 2 if control reaches the third case.

---

Here's how I would suggest you write this code instead:

```ml
let validateDuplicates (id, g : List<_>) =
    match g.Length with
    | 0 -> failwith "Unexpected"
    | 1 -> printf $"No duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | 2 -> printf $"Two duplicates for {id} is OK.\n"
    | _ -> printf $"More than two duplicates for {id} is NOT OK.\n"

input
|> validate
|> List.groupBy (fun i -> i.id)
|> List.iter validateDuplicates
```

The changes I've made are:

- Use `List.iter` instead of piping `List.forall` into `ignore`.
- Eliminate unneeded lambda in invocation of `validateDuplicates`.
- Use pattern matching to deconstruct the input to `validateDuplicates`
- Match directly on `g.Length` instead of using `when` clauses.
- Defensive programming: explicitly check for an empty list to make your intention clear.

You might also want to consider making your validation functions pure (i.e. no side-effects) via F#'s [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) type.

Comment: i am only on lesson 20 in Isaac Abraham's book :) can you give me a top-three list of issues with my code?

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional feedback.

Comment: Calculating length of linked lists is a bad habit, don't get used to it. Better match with `[]`, `[_]`, and `[_;_]`